Storm-Powered Industrial Revolution Complications/Limitations
Poseidon and Zeus are not very happy. An alien planet hosts a very stormy and volatile hydrosphere. It's of a similar temperature to Earth, except larger, with a bit more gravity, and tidal heating that gives it heavy tectonic activity.
Super Earth + Fast Rotation + Thick Atmosphere + Deep Oceans + Heavy Volcanism = Big Wet.
The tropics are dominated by superhumid rainforests, and temperate regions make England look like beach weather. Everything barring ice-caps and tundra receives monsoon rains that cause rivers to burst their banks. What would be 'desert' is more likely savanna, grassy steppe, or Mediterranean-like shrub-land, with a heavy but unpredictable wet season. Fertile, but flood-prone. Thunderstorms, Floods, Hurricanes, and Tornadoes are the average Tuesday.
The main civilisation on the planet has adapted to live with this, and utilized the storms to drive hydro-powered industry since antiquity. They're also fairly protective of nature. As such, they refuse to dig up coal or oil reserves under sacred forests.
In addition, lack of Tin to make Bronze and slow development of furnace temperatures has led to relatively slow metallurgical development. The trompe-powered furnace is the furthest they've come, and lack of coke or coal makes further development difficult. Still, they've made it into an early modern period, with most key resources (gunpowder, petroleum) derived from organic equivalents they farm, barring common minerals like iron or limestone, or anything literally as common as dirt.
They already have water management systems like dams, canals, etc. and over millennia have managed to figure out how to engineer them effectively for industry. The vast majority of industry uses watermills and hydraulics.
One potential answer they've come up with to generate heat is... with some difficulty... lightning rods. While they haven't invented electricity, they do understand electrical energy, at least to the point that lightning boils anything it strikes, and that energy can be conducted, such as heating an enclosed tank of water to store energy and increase pressure.
TLDR: a Lightning and Water-powered Industrial Revolution would be pretty absurdly different compared to just simple coal and gas. I want to know what key disadvantages, limitations and workarounds it would have on conventional industrialisation. My first concern is Steel, unless they can make a furnace hot enough to melt iron ore without coal or deforestation, but I'd like to know other limitations as well.

Do they have iron? And are you aware that you need carbon (from charcoal or wherever else) to reduce iron ore to metallic iron? And higher temperatures than smelting copper, too... making it to the early modern period with nothing much better than arsenical bronze is certainly an interesting pitch, but a tough one to justify. I'm extremely skeptical of your lightning-powered heating technology, too, but I don't really have the energy to think about it right now.

@StarfishPrime Yes, they have iron. The carbon component for ferrous metallurgy mainly comes from limestone and what little charcoal can be farmed, and it generally produces pig iron that needs to be refined further. The process is laborious and inefficient, but so was most stuff before industrialisation. They wouldn't be using such low-quality iron for weapons or armour for a while, but rather everyday tools like mattocks, hammers, etc.

Lightning seems reallllly unlikely. But your world is heavy with volcanoes. Why not give them geothermal heating?

@Rexotec FYI: Limestone is not used to carbonize steel. What it does do is help leach out impurities; so, instead of the time and fuel expensive process of waiting for slag to distill on its own, limestone binds to the impurities and helps them seperate much faster.   If you are looking at industrial era steel (late-1600s or later) then the most common practice was to blast the molten steel with hot air to fully decarbonize it, then to add a controlled amount of charcoal until you bring it back up to the desired carbon level.

Reducing pig iron via a finery process like you describe actually uses a lot more fuel and carbon emissions because you have to keep the iron molten for a lot longer, but it also kind of defeats the point of adding quicklime since your other impurities will tend to distil on thier own when you do it that way.

Do they also refuse to dig up sacred swamps, sacred grasslands, sacred tundra, sacred oceans, and so on?

If they have a lot of knowledge about forests and are willing to build bigger landscape changing infrastructure like dams, it is not unthinkable that they cultivate/farm a large forest of fast growing trees for wood in a sustainable way. Processing said wood in blast furnaces to create charcoal to produce iron seems a plausible story.

Frame Challenges First:

Lack of tin will not hold back metallurgy.  Iron use actually started at the same time as bronze use with iron and steel artifacts dating back as early as 3200 BC.  Iron is believed to have been commonly used during the bronze age, but because bronze is more corrosion resistant, there are a lot more surviving bronze pieces from this time period.  Iron replaced bronze for a lot of things that bronze was previously preferred for when the trade routes collapsed in about 1200 BC.  Because iron was already known, and necessity is the mother of invention, if you take away bronze, then all the innovations that started happened in iron working in about 1200BC would have actually begun in 3200BC.  So, by taking away tin, you will actually accelerate metallurgy, not slow it down.
Bronze is better for hydroelectric societies than iron anyway.  One of the big things that holds back wider use of hydroelectric power is the corrosiveness of water.  Many hydroelectric systems use bronze or other copper alloys to make thier turbines and bushings because bronze can take the vibrational forces better than aluminum alloys while resisting corrosion better than steel alloys. If your civilization actually never left the bronze age, because they have more plentiful copper and tin than we did, then you could design a progression of metallurgy where the kinds of alloys that are good for hydropower continued to mature early on, and the the steel alloys which are better for steam power and internal combustion engines never fully mature.
Lighting is a terrible source of energy. Obligatory XKCD. Although lightning is a very energetic event, it is also a very fast event... like, a really tiny fraction of a second.  Because of a lack of sustained power input, it will not actually heat up a meaningful amount of water.
Burning stuff for heat when electricity is not an option has been a common practice from the very beginnings of human civilization up to this day.  When wood is scarce, we burn whatever else we can get our hands on including dug, lard, peat, agricultural byproducts, and witches ... okay, maybe not witches, but the other 4 have been primary fuel sources for various civilizations throughout history.  Burning stuff to stay warm is in fact one of the easiest problems for humans to solve, regardless of the availability of electricity or modern fuel sources.

But to answer your question anyway, use Heat Pumps.
If we assume you have tons of extra hydro power capacity, but wood is scarce, or laws prevent you from starting fires in the city, then your civilization's best bet is to use heat pumps.
Since you are in an industrial revolution setting, your people should understand the basics of a heat pump.  The first heat pump powered refrigerator was built in the 1740s and the science explaining the relationship between pressure and temperature was pretty much fully understood by the 1780s. In our world it has always been well understood that a heat pump can be used both ways, but its just a lot more efficient to burn stuff directly if you want to warm a home; so, we only use them for ACs and refrigerators, not for heaters.
But by simply reversing which side is your evaporator and which side is your condenser, you can turn an air conditioner into a heater.  The only mechanical part of an AC is the compressor which could be powered mechanically by a turning water wheel; so, no electricity is required.  The most inconvenient part would be maintaining the temperature without an electrical thermostat... but if you have a lever or crank regulated weir to control the flow of water, you could probably keep things feeling nice inside with just a few manual adjustments per day.

Windmills and the Crankshaft
Look at the Dutch golden age for an actual example of industrialization without coal or steam. Numerous factors led to an enormous economic boost; one of them was technology.
See the following resources of what was possible in the late 1500s and early 1600s.
The wind powered sawmill:

https://www.houtzaagmolen-uitgeest.nl/sites/default/files/cornelis_corneliszoon_van_uitgeest_foundation_v2.pdf

https://netherlandsinsiders.com/why-is-the-netherlands-known-for-windmills/

https://www.core77.com/posts/53123/A-Brief-History-of-Wood-Splitting-Technology-Part-3-The-Wind-Powered-Sawmill-That-Changed-Dutch-History


To summarize: 10.000 windmills were built. A significant portion of them were used for wood processing and that increased productivity by a factor of 30. Windmills were also used for all sorts of material processing, and of course to pump water.
These mills were advanced machines made by skilled woodworkers. They would need to be smaller and more stubby to work on your planet. Capture stronger winds with smaller sails, so the structure doesn't get overwhelmed by the forces.
It is not an answer to the lightning question, but a real world inspiration for capturing storm energy for industry purposes.
Inside a Wind-Powered Sawmill

Milling wheat with rotating stones


The advantages of this cultural development path basically boil down to two things:

They're not wrecking their atmosphere or despoiling their water supplies (important given how rapidly stuff would get sloshed around during floods).

They've developed a deep understanding of resource management and recognize the value of gathering during windfalls and rationing that supply out as available.


#2 is an incredibly valuable mindset to have given the brutal scarcity you've set them up for.
The disadvantages are legion but chief among them are:

While lightning can make for a fun novelty demonstration of scientific principle, it doesn't actually boil as much as you'd think.  While there's a considerable amount of energy in a bolt of lightning, meaningfully using electricity requires an understanding of the important difference between power and energy.

Lightning, specifically, is a power problem. Lightning dumps 7 gigajoules, equivalent to north of 30 gallons of gasoline which isn't a mindblowing amount of energy.  The issue is that it does so over a period measured in microseconds.  To harness that energy, you need to be able to process it within that same time period.
We can't meaningfully do that with current technology and materials, let alone garbage-grade iron.
Lightning rods are a safety tool - a way to ensure that energy isn't processed by converting our homes into rapidly oxidizing chemical chain-reactions (fire).
If they understand that lightning has energy, and that (mathematically speaking) that energy could be utilized, it's likely they've got eccentrics who chase lightning-capture as their version of what nuclear fusion ("20 years away, and always will be") has been for decades (until very recently).  Perhaps someday they get there, but not before they solve the problem far more conveniently.

The other main disadvantage is the need for continuous energy supply for many processes.

They've got only one meaningful source of constant-heat supply (fire), and only three other meaningful options for constant-kinetic supply: labor, animal power, water power.
Wind is ample, but unstable/unsteady because of constant storms. Water is technically the same, but they've developed water management technologies so they've got a high-leverage option in carefully managing mechanical hydropower where they build and keep filled gigantic reservoirs that they can spill water from as needed.  That gets you triphammers and mills and all sorts of things that dominated the industrial world until steam came along.
They've got one other option for storing heat, however.  It's unable to meet true constant-temperature-needed processes, but they've got a star and it dumps a ton of heat on them whenever it's not storming.
If they've got wood and charcoal, they've got glass. If they've got glass, it's just a matter of time before they get lenses.  If they've got lenses it's just a matter of time before some poor bastard lights his research notes on fire by accident and wonders how the hell he managed to do that. (Assuming, as noted in the comments, they didn't already realize this with mirrors.)
Which means they now also understand that the light of their star can be focused to achieve directed heating.  They lack the materials to jump straight to concentrated solar power, but if you understand how that works on the theoretical level you've got several applications which are pure novelty to us, but in a fuel-starved society might be cost-effective:
Build a few mirrors and you can cook with the sun
Scale it up and you can heat stuff to smelting/forging temperature.
Mirrors are effective, not necessary, you can do it with lensing (don't get too excited about the phrase 'death ray' in the title, he mostly melts plastic toy soldiers with it)
When the storms come the systems shut off, but if you need heating for comfort you can heat up bricks and then store them in underground bunkers.
Geothermal's another idea but you mentioned heavy tectonic activity so it's not likely to give you a good return on the cost of digging that deep or near to volcanoes.
There's still the issue of chemical process control to solve but eliminating the need for entire forests to be sacrificed in the name of coal is a huge, scalable (though quite expensive and slow) way to progress down the tech tree.

One detail, concentrating solar power with mirrors precedes lenses. (Archimedes) And is much more practical, because a mirror is thin and giant lenses are heavy.

@MennovanLavieren TIL, thank you for that correction!
